# Running an XMLA Statment in SQL Query?

Tags: openrowset

I'm trying to create a new role on my analysis DB.

i have tested multiple combination :
when running a simple MDX query with Openrowset => it works.
when running the it works.
when trying to create  anew SSAS role from SQl relational DB using openrowset=> ERROR.

here is the code I'm trying

```
SELECT * FROM OpenRowset('MSOLAP', 'DATA SOURCE=servername; Initial Catalog=AnalysisDBName;',
'
<Create xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
            <ParentObject>
                <DatabaseID>AnalysisDBName</DatabaseID>
            </ParentObject>
            <ObjectDefinition>
                <Role xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ddl2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2" xmlns:ddl2_2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2/2">
                    <ID>Role 22</ID>
                    <Name>Rolename</Name>
                </Role>
            </ObjectDefinition> 
    </Create>

')
```

and the error that i receive is:

```
OLE DB provider "MSOLAP" for linked server "(null)" returned message "A required child element is missing under Envelope/soap:Body at line , column  (namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'). One of Fault, AuthenticateResponse, DiscoverResponse, ExecuteResponse was expected.".
Msg 7321, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
An error occurred while preparing the query "
<Create xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
    <ParentObject>
        <DatabaseID>AnalysisDBName</DatabaseID>
    </ParentObject>
    <ObjectDefinition>
        <Role xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ddl2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2" xmlns:ddl2_2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2/2">
            <ID>Role 22</ID>
            <Name>Rolename</Name>
        </Role>
    </ObjectDefinition>
</Create>
" for execution against OLE DB provider "MSOLAP" for linked server "(null)".
```

Please help :)
Regards,
elie

Answer (score 1):

You can add your ssas olap as linked server and then use this code:

EXEC ('XMLAsomething ....rest of your code') AT LinkedOlap

Answer (score 0):

[OPENROWSET](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312(SQL.90).aspx) expects a valid query such as "`SELECT * FROM table`" (in the correct SQL dialect of the data source specified)

The xml snippet is not a valid query in most SQL dialects, especially not T-SQL.

Unfortunately, there is no CREATE USER equivalent in MDX like T-SQL, so it can't be done via regular SQL statement or OPENROWSET.

In the [SSAS Granting User Access](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175408(SQL.90).aspx), it mentions using AMO to manage users which can't done using OPENROWSET.

Sorry, it's not an answer: I can only say how not to do it...